# How do I create a url in django and capture inputs for a search page?

Tags: python, django, search

New to Django and to programming.

I want to create a search page and currently have the following.

My urlpatterns has the following as one of it's patterns.

```
url(r'^search/$', view=search, name='search')
```

my views has a function

```
def search(request):
    if request.GET.get('q'):
        message = 'You submitted: %r' % request.GET['q']
    else:
        message = 'You submitted nothing!'
    return render(request, 'myapp/search.html', {'message': message})
```

search.html has

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Search</title>
          </head>

       <body>
       <h1> Search </h1>

      <form action="/search/"  method="get" >
      <input type="text" name = "q">
      <input type="submit"value="Search"/>
    </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

My issue is when I go to "myapp/search" i see the search box and I see in django debug toolbar that "views.search" function is captured, but when I enter text in the search box and click "search" I receive "The current URL, search/, didn't match any of these." plus the django debug toolbar shows only a GET variable capture, but nothing in Views.

1) So how do I associate 'views.search' after I click the 'search' button.

2) In my url patterns do I need another url pattern, if so what should it be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said yourself that the URL is "/myapp/search/", but the "action" parameter of your form - which determines where the form data is sent - is just "/search/". You need to make it the same, so that the data is sent to that URL.

The best way to do it is to use the `{% url %}` tag:

```
<form action="{% url "search" %}"  method="get">
```

Comment: Daniel, Thank you! I spent an inordinate amount of time trying to fix this. Is this documented in official Django documentation ?  Sorry I am unable to Vote it up since I have no 'reputation'